# How do I reverse ys?

Tags: python, list

```
def convolute_0(xs,ys):
    
sum([x*y for x,y in zip(xs,ys[::-1])])
    
    

assert convolute_0([1], [10] ) == 1*10
assert convolute_0([1,2], [10,20] ) == 1*20 + 2*10
assert convolute_0([1,2,3], [10,20,30] ) == 1*30 + 2*20 + 3*10
```

I want to multiply xs with the reversed list of ys.With [::-1] I get an assertion error.

Comment: Your method return nothing

Answer (score 1):

As @arzo commented, your method doesn't return anything that's the error. This is the way:

```py
def convolute_0(xs,ys):
    
    return sum([x*y for x,y in zip(xs,ys[::-1])])
    
assert convolute_0([1], [10] ) == 1*10
assert convolute_0([1,2], [10,20] ) == 1*20 + 2*10
assert convolute_0([1,2,3], [10,20,30] ) == 1*30 + 2*20 + 3*10
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is you can't reverse int type with ys[::-1]
you can do:

```
def convolute_0(xs,ys):

   return sum([x*int(y) for x,y in zip(xs,[i[::-1] for i in [str(i) for i in ys]])])
```

Comment: `xs` and `ys` are lists, so reverse is possible